# accounts-facebook login not working on mobile build (iOS)

Tags: facebook, meteor, meteor-accounts

I tried this tutorial
http://bulenttastan.net/login-with-facebook-using-meteor-js/

I can login into Facebook via my browser on my desktop but when I test a mobile build (iOS) it opens a popup with an error message instead of the Facebook login dialog popup. (tested with localhost:3000)

the error says that I have not configured the app urls properly. I believe its just a problem with the configuration from developer.facebook.com but I don't know how to fix this to get the Facebook login working on native builds. Can someone give me a hint wants wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: If you are looking for Mobile build you may try this https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Comment: Have you checked your FB app settings? Specifically, the domain and web platform URL.

Comment: yep had some problems with my FB settings. so ```accounts-facebook``` is working on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I have two Facebook apps, each one with its own App ID/secret. When I put the app on app.meteor.com and mobile, I use one set of keys (which on developers.facebook.com is associated with app.meteor.com), when testing locally (localhost:3000), I use the other.

```
// // USE THIS IF RUNNING ON LOCALHOST
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
   service: 'facebook'
});

ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
   service: 'facebook',
   appId: '1234',
   secret: 'asdf'
});

//USE THIS IF RUNNING ON METEOR.COM
// ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
//    service: 'facebook'
// });

// ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
//    service: 'facebook',
//    appId: '456',
//    secret: 'qwerty'
// });
```

Comment: I am currently having the same issue, my facebook app settings all seem to be there. Seems like no matter what I do I can not get it to work on the ios simulator. See my link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471977/meteor-facebook-user-accounts-works-in-browser-not-on-ios-simulator